# Error al imprimir un archivo con lpr por consola Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, imprimir

Sistema Ubuntu 20.

Utilizando el comando lpr en el mismo directorio donde está el archivo:

`lpr archivo.txt`

Me da el siguiente error:

lpr: Error - No default destinacion.

Haciendo un lpstat -p -d :

printer EPSON_XP_xxxx is idle. enabled since vie. 26 feb. 2021
no System default destination

¿Utilizo mal el comando? ¿No tengo bien configurada la impresora?
Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La repuesta (en inglés) está aquí https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=28914  Para hacer este impriimador el default,

```
lpoptions -d EPSON_XP_xxxx
```

Entonces prueba con lpq para verificar.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias Duston